# Tracing the longest path using Bellman-Ford with negative edge weights

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm currently finding the longest path in a directed acyclic positive-weighted graph by negating all edge weights and running Bellman-Ford algorithm. This is working great.

However, I'd like to print the trace of which nodes/edges were used. How can I do that?

The program takes as input the number of nodes, a source, destination and edge weight. Input halts on `-1 -1 -1`. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BellmanFord {
    public static int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    // this class represents an edge between two nodes
    static class Edge {
        int source; // source node
        int destination; // destination node
        int weight; // weight of the edge
        public Edge() {}; // default constructor
        public Edge(int s, int d, int w) { source = s; destination = d; weight = (w*(-1)); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputgood = 1;
        int tail;
        int head;
        int weight;
        int count = -1;
        Vector<Edge> edges = new Vector<Edge>(); // data structure to hold graph
        int nnodes = input.nextInt();
        while (inputgood == 1) {
            tail = input.nextInt();
            head = input.nextInt();
            weight = input.nextInt();

            if (tail != -1) {
                edges.add(new Edge(tail, head, weight));
                count++;
            }
            if (tail == -1)
                inputgood = 0;
        }
        int start = edges.get(0).source;
        bellmanFord(edges, nnodes, start);
    }

    public static void bellmanFord(Vector<Edge> edges, int nnodes, int source) {
        // the 'distance' array contains the distances from the main source to all other nodes
        int[] distance = new int[nnodes];
        // at the start - all distances are initiated to infinity
        Arrays.fill(distance, INF);
        // the distance from the main source to itself is 0
        distance[source] = 0;
        // in the next loop we run the relaxation 'nnodes' times to ensure that
        // we have found new distances for ALL nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < nnodes; ++i)
            // relax every edge in 'edges'
            for (int j = 0; j < edges.size(); ++j) {
                // analyze the current edge (SOURCE == edges.get(j).source, DESTINATION == edges.get(j).destination):
                // if the distance to the SOURCE node is equal to INF then there's no shorter path from our main source to DESTINATION through SOURCE
                if (distance[edges.get(j).source] == INF) continue;
                // newDistance represents the distance from our main source to DESTINATION through SOURCE (i.e. using current edge - 'edges.get(j)')
                int newDistance = distance[edges.get(j).source] + edges.get(j).weight;
                // if the newDistance is less than previous longest distance from our main source to DESTINATION
                // then record that new longest distance from the main source to DESTINATION
                if (newDistance < distance[edges.get(j).destination])
                    distance[edges.get(j).destination] = newDistance;
            }
        // next loop analyzes the graph for cycles
        for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i)
            // 'if (distance[edges.get(i).source] != INF)' means:
            // "
            //    if the distance from the main source node to the DESTINATION node is equal to infinity then there's no path between them
            // "
            // 'if (distance[edges.get(i).destination] > distance[edges.get(i).source] + edges.get(i).weight)' says that there's a negative edge weight cycle in the graph
            if (distance[edges.get(i).source] != INF && distance[edges.get(i).destination] > distance[edges.get(i).source] + edges.get(i).weight) {
                System.out.println("Cycles detected!");
                return;
            }
        // this loop outputs the distances from the main source node to all other nodes of the graph
        for (int i = 0; i < distance.length; ++i)
            if (distance[i] == INF)
                System.out.println("There's no path between " + source + " and " + i);
            else
                System.out.println("The Longest distance between nodes " + source + " and " + i + " is " + distance[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finding the longest path in general is computationally much harder than finding the shortest path...

Comment: @Suppressingfire, for an acyclic graph it's as simple as finding the shortest path.

Comment: You can replace the `while (inputgood == 1)` with `while (true)` and instead of `if (tail == -1) inputgood = 0;` at the end of the loop, `if (tail == -1) break;` should be placed after reading the input inside the cycle’s body. Then the `if (tail != -1)` condition will be always satisfied and can be removed.

Comment: In a DAG, you can find a topological order of vertices (in linear time) and use it to find the longest path (also in linear time). You just walk the sequence of vertices from left to right and push the longest path leading to the current vertex extended by the corresponding edge to all its neighbors, unless there is a longer path already known for the neighbor.

Comment: Related: [Longest path in a DAG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10712495/2157640)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly modify what you do in the Bellman Ford implementation:

```
...
int[] lastNode = new int[nnodes];
lastNode[source] = source;
for (int i = 0; i < nnodes; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < edges.size(); ++j) {
        if (distance[edges.get(j).source] == INF) continue;
        int newDistance = distance[edges.get(j).source] + edges.get(j).weight;
        if (newDistance < distance[edges.get(j).destination])
        {
            distance[edges.get(j).destination] = newDistance;
            lastNode[edges.get(j).destination] = edges.get(j).source;
        }
    }
```

Printing individual paths then becomes:

```
static void printPath(int source, int end, int[] lastNodes)
{
    if(source!=end)
        printPath(source, lastNodes[end], lastNodes);
    System.out.print(end+" ");
}
```

Which prints the path in order from source node to end node.

Comment: But what if the source node is a greater number than the end. Say node 10 is at the top of the graph and has the longest path to 0. Wouldn't this cause a stack overflow?

Comment: I'm not following your question. The lastNode array is storing an index to the node that led to it (mildly storing the edge that led to the current node). So long as the path has no cycles, then it will be of finite length; and printPath would print it out by tracing the path back from end to start, and then print out in order of start to end. SO, sorry, I don't follow your question; can you be more specific?

Comment: So I implement this function and add the array that stores the index of the node that led to it. Then I use this graph as input: 

11
10 4 12
10 5 11
10 6 1
4 8 3
4 7 3
5 8 2
5 7 4
5 0 2
6 7 2
6 0 1
8 9 6
8 1 5
7 9 5
7 1 6
7 2 4
0 1 4
0 2 9
9 3 7
1 3 10
2 3 8
-1 -1 -1

The longest path is 10 -> 5 -> 7 -> 1 with length 31. But for some reason the code above causes a stack overflow. I thought from the source (10) being greater than the end node (1)

Comment: I don't beleive so. The only thing that I can think that would cause that is a cycle. Try moving the System.out.print(end+" ") to the start of the printPath method, and see what you get as outputs.

Comment: That, and finally getting around to running locally with the input provided; I don't have a stack overflow, and the longest path listed for 10->1 is 10->4->7->1, length 21

Answer (score 0):

The common solution for graph algorithms is to maintain `parent[edge] -> edge` mapping.  For edge `e` the value of `parent[e]` is the node from which we traverse to `e` when we create a path optimal in some way.

The array is usually updated in the same way you update index in algorithm to find the largest element in the array, i.e. within `if` condition when you compare fitness of candidate path with that of current path.

In your case, it's here:

```
if (newDistance < distance[edges.get(j).destination]) {
   distance[edges.get(j).destination] = newDistance;
   parent[edges.get(j).destination] = edges.get(j).source;
}
```

After you comupted `parent` mapping, you may take destination node and traverse it back, recursively building an array `[dest, parent[dest], parent[parent[dest]], ... source`.