# Longest path in a DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

To find the longest path in a DAG, I'm aware of 2 algorithms: algo 1: do a topological sort + use dynamic programming on the result of the sort ~ or ~ algo 2: enumerate all the paths in the DAG using DFS, and record the longest. It seems like enumerating all the paths with DFS has better complexity than algo 1. Is that true?

Comment: Related on [CS.SE]: [Finding shortest and longest paths between two vertices in a DAG](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11295/11177)

Answer (score 10):

Your second option is incorrect: DFS does not explore all possible paths, unless your graph is a tree or a forest, and you start from the roots.  The second algorithm that I know is negating the weights and finding the shortest path, but it is somewhat slower than the [top sort + DP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Longest_path_problem&oldid=525448430#Algorithms_for_acyclic_graphs) that you listed as #1.

Comment: OK, I meant DFS with restart from any vertex that has not been visited in the previous DFS passes. That will explore the whole DAG. Shouldn't that be faster than topo sort + DP?

Comment: @Frank DFS with restart from vertexes that has not been visited will not explore all paths. Consider a graph `A->B->C`; you start DFS from B, go to C, and stop; then restart from A, go to B, and stop again, because you have visited C already. Both path that DFS found, `B-C` and `A-B`, are of length 1; the longest path `A-B-C` is of length 2.

Comment: Why would you start from B? You have to start the DFS from sources.

Comment: Even if you start at the sources, consider a graph with diamonds: `A->B,C ; B->D ; C->D ; D->E,F ; E->G ; F->G`. `A` is a source, so you start exploring from it. You go `A-B-D-E,G`, go back to `D`, try `A-B-D-F-G`, go back to `A`, try `A-C-D`, and stop, because `D` has been fully explored now. If the longest path by weight is `A-C-D-E-G`, DFS is not going to find it.

Comment: It turns out that DAG (directed acyclic graph) and tree are two names for the same thing.

Comment: @Thomash All trees are DAGs, but not all DAGs are trees.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight indeed, it was a mistake sorry.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In your example, why stop at D in the second pass? DFS usually don't stop because a previous visit fully explored it.

Comment: @Gene Although many implementations skip this "unimportant" check, [DFS algorithm does not explore fully explored vertixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, a DFS (on a DAG) which labels the current explored node by the max weight sum from the target and the child which gave it will find the longest path. You might say this is Dynamic Programming in disguise.

Comment: @max: no it will not be linear because as per the nature of DFS you will have to visit some nodes more than once. In fact it will be exponential in the number of levels in the DAG. By the way, I committed a mistake when I previously said that DFS on a DAG is kind of a DP in disguise which clearly it isn't because you are visiting the same nodes over and over again.

Comment: @RabihKodeih hmm I think it is linear with proper implementation: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-algorithm-to-find-a-longest-path-in-a-unweighted-directed-acyclic-graph/answer/Chun-Ho-Hung?srid=putc. Do you see any problem with that solution?

Answer (score 3):

Enumerate all paths in a DAG using "DFS":

```
import numpy as np

def enumerate_dag(g):

    def enumerate_r(n, paths, visited, a_path = []):
        a_path += [n]
        visited[n] = 1
        if not g[n]:
            paths += [list(a_path)]
        else:
            for nn in g[n]:
                enumerate_r(nn, paths, visited, list(a_path))

    paths, N = [], len(g)
    visited = np.zeros((N), dtype='int32')

    for root in range(N):
        if visited[root]: continue
        enumerate_r(root, paths, visited, [])

    return paths
```

Comment: Did you try passing a double-diamond graph to this code? It looks like it has a 50/50 chance of missing the longest path.

Comment: I've just tried with: [[1,2],[3],[3],[4],[5,6],[7],[7],[8],[9],[]]. I get 4 paths: [[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]], which I believe is the correct answer. As far as I can tell (from many other tests), this algorithm correctly enumerates the paths in a DAG. Topo sort is based on a very similar use of DFS. Provided you start/restart at sources, DFS will explore *all* the nodes reachable from each source hence the code above *completely* explores the DAG, no vertex is missed.

Comment: I misunderstood the use of `visited` in your code: you set it, but you do not use it to decide if you should continue the traversal. This is not what's called [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), because DFS does not visit nodes that have been completely explored. The biggest difference between DFS and your code is that your code is hugely inefficient. Try repeating the same diamond pattern fifty times to see what I mean: your program will explore all `2^50` paths, and that's a lot of paths to explore.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the exploration strategy of the DAG is "DFS": it expands each path to a sink, then backtracks. As for "hugely inefficient", the intent IS to enumerate all the paths for this function. So yes, it has to visit some nodes many times.

Comment: But I can see how enumerating all the paths to find the longest one is going to have bad complexity compared to topo sort + ordering.

Comment: Enumerating all paths makes the complexity exponential, rendering the algorithm very much useless for the general case. Top sort + DP is polynomial; so is the shortest path on negated edges.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, the compared complexities of the different approaches. I must have been sleepy not to see right away that the enumeration was exponential.

Comment: @Frank What is the structure of the expected graph `g` ?

Answer (score 3):

No DFS needed.
Algorithm : takes a DAG G.
Each arc holds one variable E

```
for each node with no predecessor :
    for each of his leaving arcs, E=1.
for each node whose predecessors have all been visited :
    for each of his leaving arcs, E=max(E(entering arcs))+1.
```

max_path is the highest E within edges when all nodes have been processed.

Comment: This is the correct answer; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths