# Finding maximum length of a path in an 2D array with given condition

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi I am new to stack overflow. I need help to solve the below issue in a java program

I have a 2D array, i need to find out the maximum length that can traverse from any node. I can traverse from one element to connected element (left/right/top/bottom) if that has lesser value than current element. i need to find the maximum path that can be possible with the above condition in a 2D integer array
 below is 5*5 array

```
  7  2  3  4  5 
  36 37 38 34 6 
  33 44 46 40 7 
  24 43 42 41 8 
  35 32 47 30 9
```

Longest path in the above array is 46-44-43-42-41-30-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2 total 14.

please help me on this writing Java code.Thanks in advance

Comment: hi Oli Charlesworth, i have tried the recursion program,i have created a duplicate array with same size to keep the track of visited nodes and a stack with the coordinate objects. but i could not make it possible

Answer (score 1):

Represent the data as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), where `G=(V,E)` and `V={ all squares}`, `E = { (u,v) | u is adjacent to v and u.value < v.value)`

Note that the above graph is a [Directed Acyclic Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (since if (u,v) is in E, there is no path from `v` to `u`, because it will require a path `v->v1->v2->...->u` such that `v.value > v1.value > v2.value > .... > u.value`, but `operator>` is transitive so it means `v.value > u.value`, and we know `v.value < u.value` - because `(u,v)` is in `E`, so it is a contradiction, and such a path cannot exist).

After this reduction - you can simply solve [longest path in a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10712495/572670), which is a simpler problem.

Comment: hi amit i am not much aware of constructing a graph can you please elaborate me in constructing the graph

Comment: @sivakumar Did you read the wiki article I linked to? You should also read the article about the [graph data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29) if you are not familiar with it, try implementing it and let me know if you have a specific issue with it.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no standard library implementation of a graph in java. writing one that fulfills the requirements of this problem should be fairly straightforward.