# Find longest path in DAG with positive and negative edges using Bellman-ford and negated edge

Tags: graph, path, directed-acyclic-graphs, bellman-ford

I've got a graph that spans out like a tree (see crude drawing below. Can't post a picture unfortunately). It's a DAG, all of the edges should point rightwards. All the edges going up will have negative weights, all the ones going down will have positive weights. The diameter of the graph will be 48 across, but the height could be limited to 5, or 7, or others depending on the scenario.

```
        O-O...
       / X 
      O-O-O...
     / X X
    O-O-O-O...
     \ X X
      O-O-O...
       \ X
        O-O...
```

I want to find the longest path from the starting node to the last node 48 nodes later. After some research, it seems like I could negate all the values (* -1), find the shortest path using Bellman-ford, and that should give me the longest path in linear time? (page 37/40 of http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2011/lectures/04_class.pdf)

I know that it should work if you are negating the edges if they are all positive initially. But does that still apply if some of them are positive and some of them are negative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Longest path in a DAG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712495/longest-path-in-a-dag)

Comment: Yes, it works. Bellman-Ford algorithm has problems only with negative cycles – but they cannot occur in a DAG as there are no cycles at all. But there is a much faster and easier to implement algorithm using topological sort and dynamic programming. See [Longest path in a DAG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10712495/2157640).