# Number Maze Solving Algorithm

Tags: java, maze

I am working on a solver for a unique type of maze, referred to as a "number maze". Essentially every position you are at is a number (1-4) which denotes the next possible move locations (upward, downward, diagonal). Here is an illustration to clarify what I am talking about.

[image]

Lastly, every position can only be visited once. The goal is to be able to find the longest path through the maze.

Currently I can successfully find the possible moves from each location and iterate through all possible paths in the maze. The program does not know what the “end” of the maze is, but that is easy to implement later. The issue that I am currently having is that I do not know how to implement “memory of paths” in order to analyze all the possible paths and find out which one is the longest. Essentially I need a way to store all of the different paths and then analyze them. I attempted to do so with `ArrayList<String> MovePath`, however that ended up not working. I think the whole recursion aspect of this is tripping me up. All the important parts of my code is posted below. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
private static String changeString(String currentstring, String addendum) {
        return currentstring + addendum;
    }

static ArrayList<String> solve(int X, int Y, String path, ArrayList<String> MovePath, int[][] PuzzleBoard) {

        if (PuzzleBoard[X][Y] == 0) {
            //If current position is blank, don't attempt to find moves

    } else {

        ArrayList<Point> AllMoves = FindMoves(PuzzleBoard, X, Y); //Find possible moves from current board location based on piece type


        for (int i = 0; i < AllMoves.size(); i++) {//Iterate through possible moves
            PuzzleBoard[X][Y] = 0; //set current position to 0 (empty)
            X = (int) AllMoves.get(i).getX();//get move X coordinate
            Y = (int) AllMoves.get(i).getY();//get move Y coordinate

            String xstring = String.valueOf(X);
            String ystring = String.valueOf(Y);

            path = changeString(path, xstring);//Adds the current X coordinate to a string
            path = changeString(path, ystring);//Adds the current Y coordinate to a string

            MovePath.add(path);

            solve(X, Y, path, MovePath, PuzzleBoard);

        }
    }

    return MovePath;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[][] BoardArray = new int[][]{
            {4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0},
            {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9}
        //0 = empty
       //9 = end

    int x = 0; //starting x
    int y = 0; //starting y
    String paths = "";
    ArrayList<String> MovePath = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Answer = new ArrayList<String>();

    Answer = solve(x, y, paths, MovePath, BoardArray)

    String longestpath = Collections.max(Answer, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()));
    System.out.println(longestpath);

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you break your problem in smaller parts and then solve it:

1- It is a simple graph shortest path finding problem. So the first step is to build a graph matrix out of your data. The nodes with numbers on it can travel to the adjacent (n nodes away) nodes with the cost of the number indicated in that cell so in your example, the cost of moving from `(0,0)` to `(0,4)/(4,0)/(4/4)` is `4` and so on. So as I mention, reduce your problem to a graph

2- (for shortest possible path) Implement any path finding algorithm you want on your solution. I suggest `Dijkstra` or `A*` algorithm which is faster but you can also try `depth first` or `breadth first` search if you like. There are many tutorials and examples on implementing these algorithms on the internet. I found [this](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-mplement-dijkstras-algorithm-using-priority_queue/) for `Dijkstra` and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38376/a-search-algorithm) for `A*`.

3- (for longest possible path) Negate all weights and use Bellman-Ford algorithm to find the shortest path. Because you negated all weights you will find the longest path as the result. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776319/tracing-the-longest-path-using-bellman-ford-with-negative-edge-weights) can help you.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

my first thought is add a var that contains the maximum path, that will be updated after all finished path. Store the depth of recursion and compare it to max after finish.